# MVC3 How to access this code from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In a razor section

```
@{
 Like This
}
```

I need to be able to call the c# function

```
static T Cast<T>(object o)
{
 return (T)o;
}
```

In order to dynamically cast an object. How can I access this code?

I would like to be able to do this

```
someObject = Cast<someType>(someObject);
```

**Edit**

I am trying to implement a generic view model.

Here is the model:

```
public class GenericVM<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public List<TEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    public object Entity { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

I am filling the GenericVM object in the controller then passing it in to a view with `@model dynamic`.

Once in the view, I am attempting to use the Type from the object to dynamically cast the model back to the proper type.

Comment: Your view model should already be providing the view with the data in the form that it needs.  There really should be no need to do this.

Comment: Can't agree more with tvanfosson.

Comment: @tvanfosson - The view model, be gentle, is `@model dynamic`, so it needs to be dynamically recast.

Comment: @TravisJ, that's your problem. Instead of `@model dynamic` you should use a real view model which is known at compile time. Also I don't see why you are trying to reinvent the cast operator in C#.

Comment: I am just trying new things, I realize this may not be "by the book".

Comment: Didn't really ask if this was best practice, the question is actually rather simple in that all I needed to do was access a c# function in a razor block.

Comment: Why do you need a function to do casting? Can't you cast directly?

Comment: I think it would be better to explain what your actual goal is. I am sure there are better ways to achieve it. I see no sense in the following line of code: `someObject = Cast<someType>(someObject);`. Really, what's the point?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I will try to elaborate on the goal in an edit.

Comment: If it's dynamic just use it as if it were that type.  There's no need to cast it.  I'd feel uncomfortable having a view model that's dynamic, why not just use the ViewBag after all, but it should work as long as you pass a type with the expected properties/methods.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Great point about just using it. Although I cannot know what type it is before runtime, I have been able to still iterate through the members. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put it into an Html extension?

```
public static T Cast<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, object o)
{
    return (T)o;
}
```

Then just:

```
Html.Cast<string>(someString)
```

From your view. I use a string here as a usage example, just change for your own model type.

Answer (score 1):

Could just simply cast it or am I missing something?

```
@{
    var someObject2 = (someType)someObject;
}
```

or

```
@{
    var someObject2 = someObject as someType;
}
```

Comment: His cast method seems to take an argument which you are not providing.